# 'Block' with 'Compile' gives an error

Tags: warning-messages, compile

Here is a minimal example to the problem I face when using `Compile` with `Block`:

```
G1[x_, y_]:=Block[{ks = x y, id = Sin[x y]}, {(id - ks), (id + ks)}]
myFun = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},Block[{f = G1[x, y]}, f[[1]] x + f[[2]]],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

Once I run this code I get this error:

```
Compile::part: Part specification f[[1]] cannot be compiled since the argument is not a tensor of sufficient rank. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an old and rather often discussed issue. The output of

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[myFun]
```

contains

```
MainEvaluate[ Hold[G1][ R0, R1]]
```

and this tells us that `G1` has not been inlined correctly. Best way to circumvent this issue is to use `With` for inlining:

```
G1[x_, y_] := Block[{ks = x y, id = Sin[x y]}, {(id - ks), (id + ks)}]
myFun = With[{f = G1[x, y]},
   Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
    f[[1]] x + f[[2]],
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
    ]
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is it possible to use `:=` with compile? like this `myFun2[fun_] := 
  With[{f = G1[x, y]},Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, fun.(f[[1]] x + f[[2]]), 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]];`. `fun` are many different long and complicated function with respect to `(x,y)` that I would like to compile each of them.

Comment: You're welcome. Well again, it should work if you use `With` for inlining. Like in `myFun2[fun_] := 
  With[{code = fun.(G1[x, y][[1]] x + G1[x, y][[2]])}, 
   Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, code, CompilationTarget -> "C"]];`.

Comment: Just one more question, please? How can I get the results for `fun=x y` and at point `(x,y)=(1,1)`.

Comment: `cf = myFun2[{x,y}]` to get the compile function and then `cf[1,1]` to do the computation.

Comment: For simplicity I assume `fun=x` then I try this `rt = myFun2[x]` but I get this error: `Compile::cplist: x should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.`

Comment: Well, you wrote `fun.(f[[1]] x + f[[2]])`. `.` means `Dot`. So of course `fun` and `f[[1]] x + f[[2]]` have to be things that can be `Dot`ted against each other, i.e., tensors. Obviously, `fun = x` is not a tensor -- you told your compiled function that `x` is a real scalar.